# Is there a way to create an option group in android spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

does anyone know how to create an option group in android spinner? I want to do something like this:

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

[Demo here.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_optgroup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use a `ExpandableListView` and add it into a dialog